# How to randomly re-render the DOM nodes' order of precedence from a node-list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, shuffle, nodelist

I'm trying to shuffle cards by reordering the index of the nodes in my `NodeList`.

How can I achieve removing and appending the children of a class attribute I have?

HTML:

```
<div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/1.png" alt="">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/7.png" alt="">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/1.png" alt="">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png" alt="">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function shuffleCards() {
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
    let cardsArray = Array.from(cards);
    // reorder the nodes of the nodelist (cards)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways you can go about "shuffling" an array. I chose the Fisher-Yates method in an experimental "war" card game.
https://github.com/scottm85/war/blob/master/src/Game/Deck.js#L80

```
shuffle()
{
    /* Use a Fisher-Yates shuffle...If provides a much more reliable shuffle than using variations of a sort method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle */
    let cards = this.cards;
    for (let i = cards.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)); // random index from 0 to i
        [cards[i], cards[j]] = [cards[j], cards[i]];
    }
    this.cards = cards;

    console.log("----------------- Deck Shuffled -----------------");
}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Granted my provided example is slightly different than your needs as I was doing this in react, had a Deck array built out, and wasn't using JS for direct DOM manipulation. In theory though, you could modify this to work with your method. Something like this:

```
function shuffleCards
{
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
    let cardsArray = Array.from(cards);

    for (let i = cardsArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)); // random index from 0 to i
        [cardsArray[i], cardsArray[j]] = [cardsArray[j], cardsArray[i]];
        cards[i].remove();
    }

    cardsArray.forEach(t => document.body.appendChild(t));
}
```

Comment: In the end, I learned and used Fisher-Yates Thanks, 1 part I didn't understand, why we do i > 0 in the loop.

Comment: @Alwayslearning Because every iteration we're subtracting 1 from i. (i--;) Since you can't access an item at a negative index, we want it to stop at zero. Technically it should have been i >= 0 though, which I just noticed with your comment. I'm glad it helped though! Good luck on your project. Feel free to accept this as the answer if you feel it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` and `Math.random()` methods like this:

```js
 function shuffleCards() {
            var parent = document.getElementById("parent");

            let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
            let cardsArray = Array.from(cards);

            //console.log(cardsArray)

            cardsArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

            //console.log(cardsArray)

            cardsArray.forEach(t => parent.appendChild(t));
            // reorder the nodes of the nodelist (cards)
        }
```

```html
<h3> Click on card to Shuffle at the same postion</h3>

    <div id="parent">
        <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="shuffleCards(this)">
            card 1
            <img src="img/cards/1.png" alt="">
            <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="shuffleCards(this)">
            card 2
            <img src="img/cards/7.png" alt="">
            <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="shuffleCards(this)">
            card 3
            <img src="img/cards/1.png" alt="">
            <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works, even tho I'm trying to achieve shuffle after every game or when loading the page and keep the cards in the same position in the DOM, can I append the cards back to the same place in the DOM? currently, it seems that it's showing them after all my divs in the HTML

Comment: @Alwayslearning Yes you can. you need to put all of them in parent element and then and empty the innerHTML of the parent Element and the append shuffled node list as child of parent element

Comment: @Alwayslearning I updated the answer. Now the shuffled element are appended at the same place

Comment: Using `cardsArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);` for shuffling is a bad idea. The standard requires that the sort function is consistent. If not the outcome is implementation defined. In the worst case only part of the array is shuffled. @Alwayslearning

Comment: Thanks for the code and information that it's a bad idea, I ended up making a solution from different answers in here and using Fisher-Yates algorithms, I wasn't allowed also to use arrow functions in this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided algorithms for the randomization portion, but here is how you can handle the detaching and reattaching portion.  [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) will get you the node detached from the DOM and [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) will allow you to add it.  Just be careful with attaching and detaching.  Events can get a bit messy especially if you end up cloning the node somewhere down the line rather than just attaching it again.

```js
(function shuffleCards() {
  let container = document.querySelector('#container');
  let cards = container.querySelectorAll('.card');

  [...cards].map(
    node => container.removeChild(node)
  ).sort(
    () => Math.random() - 0.5 // shamelessly stolen from Alireza Ahmadi
  ).forEach(
    node => container.appendChild(node)
  );
})()
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 4
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 5
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 6
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 7
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 8
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 9
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      Card 10
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because of its randomness `Math.random() - 0.5` can never provide to a stable `sort` algorithm.

Comment: @PeterSeliger This is true.  The sort algorithm can be anything.  With my answer, I was wanting to address the part of OP's question where they were asking how to detach and reattach the nodes.

Comment: No problem for just DOM-node demonstration purposes. The comment was also more for the OP in order to not just blindly copying the *poor mans shuffle* approach.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is agnostic to where the queried nodes need to be removed from, and after shuffling, have to be inserted into again.

Thus one does not need to know anything about the DOM structure except for the element query.

Basically ...

1. Use only reliable/proven shuffle functions like [`_.shuffle`](https://underscorejs.org/#shuffle).
2. Create an array from the queried node list.
3. Map it with node items in a way that each (child) node gets removed from the DOM but preserves not only its own reference but also the reference of its parent node.
4. Shuffle the mapped array.
5. Iterate the shuffled items in a way where from each item one can restore the former parent-node child-node relationship ...

```js
function shuffleArray(arr) {
  let idx;
  let count = arr.length;

  while (--count) {
    idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (count + 1));
    [arr[idx], arr[count]] = [arr[count], arr[idx]];
  }
  return arr;
}

function shuffleCards() {
  const removedNodeDataList = Array
    .from(document.querySelectorAll('.card'))
    .map(elmNode => ({
      parentNode: elmNode.parentNode,
      elementNode: elmNode.parentNode.removeChild(elmNode),
    }));

  shuffleArray(removedNodeDataList)
    .forEach(({ parentNode, elementNode }) =>
      parentNode.appendChild(elementNode)
    );
}

function init() {
  document
    .querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click', shuffleCards);
}
init();
```

```css
img { background-color: #eee; }
button { display: block; margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
```

```html
<button>Shuffle Cards</button>

<div class="card" data-card="1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/140/50?grayscale" alt="">
  <img class="back" src="https://picsum.photos/120/50?grayscale" alt="">
</div>
<div class="card" data-card="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/50?grayscale" alt="">
  <img class="back" src="https://picsum.photos/160/50?grayscale" alt="">
</div>
<div class="card" data-card="3">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/180/50?grayscale" alt="">
  <img class="back" src="https://picsum.photos/80/50?grayscale" alt="">
</div>
```